# Getting error while using nltk.classify.apply_features

Tags: python, nltk, sentiment-analysis

I am new to NLTK library of Python and writing my first  program using it. The program is about analysis of tweets. The below get_feature function returns features(which is a dictionary). Using these feature I have to create a training set. However in the training set , when I am passing the get_feature function and tweets(list of tuples), its giving me error as 'dict' object is not callable'.
There is some issue while creating the training set.

Am I passing the right type of values to `nltk.classify.apply_features()`?

I tried using `nltk.classify.util.apply_features()` but no use. Can someone please let me know as in where I am getting wrong.

```
Error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/sanjiv/PycharmProjects/NLP/twitterAnalysis.py", line 98, in <module>
    ta.train_set(store_features,ta.twitter())
  File "C:/Users/sanjiv/PycharmProjects/NLP/twitterAnalysis.py", line 88, in train_set
    print train_set
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\compat.py", line 487, in wrapper
    return method(self).encode('ascii', 'backslashreplace')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\compat.py", line 475, in wrapper
    return transliterate(method(self))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\compat.py", line 487, in wrapper
    return method(self).encode('ascii', 'backslashreplace')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\util.py", line 664, in __repr__
    for elt in self:
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\util.py", line 845, in iterate_from
    try: yield self._func(self._lists[0][index])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\classify\util.py", line 65, in lazy_func
    return (feature_func(labeled_token[0]), labeled_token[1])
TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
```

The code is:

```
import nltk
import operator
from nltk.classify.util import apply_features

class TwitterAnalysis:
def __init__(self):
    pass

    @staticmethod
    def twitter():
        tweets = []
        tweets_word = []
        new_words = []
        # Positive tweets
        pos_tweets = [('I love this movie', 'positive'), ('This view is amazing', 'positive'),
                      ('Loving this morning', 'positive'),
                      ('he is my best friend', 'positive')]

        #Negative tweets
        neg_tweets = [('I do not like this car', 'negative'), ('This view is horrible', 'negative'),
                      ('I am feeling lazy this morning', 'negative'), ('He is my enemy', 'negative')]

        #Combining both type of tweets into single list and eliminating words less then size of 2

        combined_lst = [pos_tweets + neg_tweets]
        #list comprehension

        for (words, sentiment) in pos_tweets + neg_tweets:
            new_words = []

            for each in words.split():
                if len(each) >= 3:
                    new_words.append(each.lower())
            #print new_words
            tweets.append((new_words, sentiment))
        #contains tweet with sentiment
        return tweets


    def get_features(self, document, all_words,tweets):
        document_features = set(document)
        features = {}
        for each in all_words:
            features['contains(%s)' % each] = (each in document_features)
        #feature set
        return features

    def train_set(self,get_features,tweets):
        train_set = nltk.classify.util.apply_features(get_features,tweets)
        print train_set
```

Comment: Could you cut down your code to specifically the lines which are not working? (By the way doing so will often enable you to debug it yourself)

Comment: Also from your code it's not clear what arguments are supposed to be passed as `document`, `all_words` etc. You should specify what you're trying to pass, and how you expect your program to behave.

Comment: for now document is a list words used in  tweet such as ['love','this','movie']. all_words is a list of total words in the tweet, and tweets is a list of tuple having tweets with  sentiments(positive or negative)

Comment: Were you able to find the solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is from the `nltk.classify.util.apply_features` source code (reading the source usually helps!)

```
  """
def apply_features(feature_func, toks, labeled=None):
    Use the ``LazyMap`` class to construct a lazy list-like
    object that is analogous to ``map(feature_func, toks)``.  In
    particular, if ``labeled=False``, then the returned list-like
    object's values are equal to::

        [feature_func(tok) for tok in toks]

    If ``labeled=True``, then the returned list-like object's values
    are equal to::

        [(feature_func(tok), label) for (tok, label) in toks]"""
```

You'll notice that the `get_features` function you implemented takes 3 inputs, but `apply_features` accepts only 2 (and labeled=True/None).

I don't know exactly what results you're trying to extract, but you probably want to pass some default arguments to `get_features` or have it call `self` methods.

Comment: get_features is giving me correct output as expected. Only when I am trying to used the output of get_features(which is a dictionary-features) in train_set function. I am getting the said error.

Comment: because `apply_features` will call `get_features` for every `tweet` in `tweets` like this: `get_features(tweets[index])`  - can you see why that doesn't work for you?

Comment: I have done some changes to the program and I am getting the features(from get_features function) but when I am passing this to create a training set,  my training set is 'None'.                                                            training_set=nltk.classify.apply_features(extract_features,tweets)                 output - [(None, 'positive'), (None, 'positive'), ...]